# Why Can't Google Console Verify my Identity

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I've had issue with google play for a while now. When I try to send them our government approved document, NIN (National ID) it keeps rejcting it, even though they asked for a National Identity card.

I've researched and discovered this [problem is not unique](https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/178795640/identity-verification),

This is what it says anytime I try it;

```
Your identity could not be verified for the following reasons:

    Government Issued Photo ID: The document type you submitted is not supported. Provide a different type of document.
```

The other official document I have they don't accept it, which is the Voter's card. They ask for;

Passport

National Identity Card

Residence Permit.

This is really eating me up, I started learning how to code and Android Development in 2020, gave up a lot of things for this, now I can't even publish an App, even though I've Apps sitting waiting to be publish.

**My Question; Have you experienced this before? And How did you fix it?**

Keep in mind the documents I'm submitting are Nigerians', because I'm Nigerian.

I'll forever appreciate any help, recommendation or Idea.

Thanks in Advance for your understanding and assistance.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks CommonsWare. I actually have gone back and forth with console support team. But they have provided nothing that can be of help.

Comment: Hello Edwin pls have resolved this issue.